# How do |= and &= work?

Tags: c++, enums, operators

I want to make an enum in such a way that I can & parameters after |ing them in.

Can I simply do:

```
enum Things
{
   Something,
SomethingElse
};
```

Or must I be careful to give them specific numbers for this to work?

Also if a value, like say, 3, has already been |='d in, would |= it in again cause this to malfunction (as in, if(attributes & 3) would no longer work)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then define  your enum as:

```
enum Things
{
   Something = 1       //0000 0001
   SomethingElse = 2;  //0000 0010
   SomethingX = 4;     //0000 0100
   SomethingY = 8;     //0000 1000
   SomethingZ = 16;    //0001 0000
};
```

The idea is, only one bit in the binary representation should be `1`, others should be `0`, as shown in the comments above. Also, I used 8 bits only in the comment, that doesn't mean that the enum values are one byte size. I only used them for convenience. Enum values can be very large, can hold even `long`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use special values, namely powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...).
And you should probably read this before investigating this "| and & feature" any further:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system

This might also be worth reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

Packing flags with `|` and `&` works best when you take advantage of the computer's native binary encoding.

So, using the powers of 2 (here in decimal representation):

```
enum Things
{
   Something     = 1,
   SomethingElse = 2,
   SomethingMore = 4,
   SomethingHuge = 8
};
```

This enables each flag to be represented *exclusively* in a single bit of an integer, allowing each one to be activated and de-activated individually.

The result is:

```
char x = 0;
x |=  Something;     // x in binary looks like 00000001
x |=  SomethingMore; // x in binary looks like 00001001
x &= ~Something;     // x in binary looks like 00001000
```

I hope that this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bit-wise operations with an Enum, the values must be a power of 2. This is commonly referred to as a [Bit Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Comment: The terminology "bit field" shouldn't be used in this way when working in C or C++, due to [the unrelated language feature of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields).

Comment: @Tomalak: The Wikipedia article explains what's going on pretty well. But you're right, in C or C++ the term "flag(s)" is far more common, and less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

As Nawaz said and you can make it easier if you use a hexadecimal codes

```
enum Things
{
   Something =     0x00000001   //0000 0001
   SomethingElse = 0x00000002;  //0000 0010
   SomethingX    = 0x00000004;  //0000 0100
   SomethingY    = 0x00000008;  //0000 1000
   SomethingZ    = 0x00000010;  //0001 0000 // instead of 16
   SomethingZ2   = 0x00000020;  //0010 0000 // instead of 32
   SomethingZ3   = 0x00000040;  //0100 0000 // instead of 64
   SomethingZ4   = 0x00000080;  //1000 0000 // instead of 128
};
```

Or even better use a macro:

```
#define BITMASK(x) (1<<(x))

enum Things
{
   Something =    BITMASK(0)   //0000 0001
   SomethingElse = BITMASK(1) ;  //0000 0010
   SomethingX    = BITMASK(2) ;  //0000 0100
   SomethingY    = BITMASK(3) ;  //0000 1000
   SomethingZ    = BITMASK(4) ;  //0001 0000 
};
```